# How to add input box when other option is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store values from select option in database. I have an option of `others`, when I select it another input box opens and I fill data in it and submit and the data stored in database. Till now everything is perfectly working. Problem is that when I select any other options other than `others` option then it is not storing in database.

Here is my script :

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
        if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

here is my HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="organisation" class="form-control" id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
    <option>--Select Organisation--</option>
    <option id="admOption" value="0">Others</option>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="admDivCheck" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="organisation" class="form-control" placeholder="Organisation Name" />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, Please help me out.

Form :

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value="" required="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="organisation" class="form-control" id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
                <option>--Select Organisation--</option>
                <option id="admOption" value="0">Others</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btnContact" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "... then it is not storing in database." What is not storing in the database? What is the end result when you select "test1" or "test2" and submit the form? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Also, I don't see any of the code for submission. Does the `<form>` element have an `action` attribute? You should show this in your HTML snippet. Does the `<form>` have an `onSubmit` handler instead? Again, show this in yoru code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice When I select test 1 or test 2 then its value is not storing in database

Comment: We need a more complete code example to help you. Show the smallest amount of code **that illustrates what you are trying to do**. My second comment has a few suggestions on what more information might help me understand what you are doing. For more tips on creating a good code example, see [mcve].

Comment: And read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added above my full form

Comment: I still don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you have posted. You will need to debug your code to find out what is goinog on. You will need to debug both the relevant JavaScript code as well as the backend route that this form posts to. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips to get you started.

Comment: Backend routes are fine, I don't understand why its not storing other options in database.

Comment: May be what you are storing in database is the textbox with id 'admDivCheck'.  When you are not clicking others - the submitted value will be _POST['organisation'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not storing in the database because there are two fields with the same name 'organisation' One with the input field and the other with the select field. When other option is selected then show the input field and the value added in input field will store in the database.

You can do something like this.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value="" required="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="organisation" class="form-control" id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
                <option>--Select Organisation--</option>
                <option id="admOption" value="0">Others</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="admDivCheck"></div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btnContact" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Add the input field using javascript

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect){
        if(nameSelect){
            admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
            if(nameSelect.value == admOptionValue){
              document.getElementById("admDivCheck").textContent= "";
                document.getElementById("admDivCheck").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin","<input type='text' name='organisation' class='form-control' placeholder='Organisation Name' />")
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("admDivCheck").textContent= "";
            }
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").textContent= "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check here, on selecting others Input box is not opening https://jsfiddle.net/Bhawesh7731/yp5098us/

Comment: @BhaweshBhakar I have updated the js code check it.